# Remarkable general proof of substitution rule in integration

Tags: proof-verification, indefinite-integrals

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

I have discovered this general proof of rule of substitution that I came across while taking my course in integral calculus. I was bothered by this “multiplying” $dx$ thing but did not find a satisfactory explanation either on the Internet or in books. So I proved it myself.

It is general in the sense that it does not deal with $t=g(x)$ or $g(x)=t$ cases separately. In these cases, invertibility of function also comes into picture.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I dont know how else to show my work.

Comment: Is this a proof-verification question? You could add that tag. But you should also strongly consider learning how to format your formulas using the advice in the MSE help pages. Your handwriting is good, but many of us still dislike looking at photographs of equations.

Comment: You could have gotten the boxed thing from the second line without all the "derivations."

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Randall that is what I set out to prove: the use of differentials.

Comment: @David K ain’t got no time for that lol